# Convert bitmap into night vision(AUTO) filter like camScanner app

Tags: android, image-processing, android-ndk

I am making application for reading card data. I tried GPUImage,NDK and other image processing libraries for filtering image into different filters like black & white and night vision.

In camscanner app, there is AUTO filter which convert captured image into readable form just like night vision so that it can easily read from it.

Below are the sample which i am looking for:

**Original image:**

[image]

**Filtered image:**

[image]

Can anyone please help me into right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Just clone and run it, when you apply filter on image **B & W filter** is your solution.

https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo